# Piedmont, California boundaries for the purposes of school district

Tags: real-estate

We're contemplating a move to Piedmont, CA for a better school district than where we are now. Trouble is: I get different boundaries of Piedmont on Zillow and Realtor. Realtor's listings for Piedmont also include many addresses that are Oakland. Is that simply a bug on Realtor.com, or there's more to it?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic (yes, it affects the value of the thing you're buying, but by that logic, any shopping question would be on-topic). However, googling "Piedmont Unified School District borders" got this: https://www.piedmont.k12.ca.us/district-info/boundaries/ You might also want to just ask the school district what's going on. PS: Note that "unified" means that elementary and high schools have the same district. That's not the case everywhere, so in general you should check whether the district is unified, and if not, look at borders for both elementary and high school.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not a personal finance question.

Comment: It's about buying a house. Finance doesn't get more personal than that.

Comment: Many real estate tools online allow you to show map overlays of actual school districts, not just municipal boundaries. Perhaps you were comparing the municipal boundary from one source to the school district boundary from another?

Comment: I live in a town where the "old" part is in the neighboring city's school district (not very good) and the new part uses another neighboring city's school district (excellent). When you start narrowing down to potential houses, call the district and ask them which schools.

Comment: Another thing is that the "city" listed on mailing addresses in the US is the designated city of the zip code, and does not indicate that actual political city that includes the address. Some zip code cities are not real incorporated "cities" at all, and some political cities are so big that some zip codes are listed under the neighborhood name as zip code city. And zip code boundaries often do not correspond to political administrative boundaries, so some houses in one city can have another city in the address.

Answer (score 1):

Real estate listings are designed to convey location, not school district.

I once lived in a "town" that had a common name and everyone called it that, "Oh, I live in Foo".   However, if you looked on the political map, there was another city 5 miles away called BarBaz, that was shaped like a dog bone.  It had a 5 mile long, 100 foot strip of land that contained nothing but a power line. At one end was the city of BarBaz as everyone knows it. But at the other end was a blob that nearly enveloped Foo, placing most of Foo actually inside BarBaz.   Indeed, BarBaz provided the city water, sent the police and collected the property tax.  But everyone called it Foo.

This was done for tax-base reasons; without it BarBaz would have very little.

Real estate listings would claim the house was in Foo.  That's because if they said the house was in BarBaz, people would think the house was miles from where it actually was.

Down in the fine print, it would state "School district: BarBaz" which wasn't so bad, because BarBaz had a separate set of schools in the Foo area. Better funded, of course.

So when a listing says "Piedmont" they mean easy access to Piedmont shops, not entitlement to Piedmont schools.  You should tell your Realtor that Piedmont schools is a dealbreaker. If you have a family, your Realtor should have figured that out.

Comment: It should be no surprise that Realtor.com serves the interests of... wait for it... Realtors, while Zillow, less so.